# What's the best approach to change view properties due to accelerometer-value-changes?

Tags: iphone, uikit, accelerometer

I want to do this: If the device moves (accelerometer values change), then I want to adjust some values in my view according to that movement.

Would I invoke a method every time an accelerometer value changes? I believe that would be a bad idea, since they might refresh too often.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about too frequent changes, just use an accumulator; use a little bit of code that detects the changes, and checks the system time; only if enough system time has passed, do you fire the (potentially accumulated) change method.

Comment: yeah that sounds pretty good. So that accumulator is a sleek and lightweight method I implement somewhere (where?)?

Answer (score 1):

I think so... If not you have only one option. Getting a reading periodically. Again shorter the period, higher the accuracy. So it might be more efficient if you can trigger an event when a change in value is detected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about noise coming from the accelerometer you can smooth out the inputs by implementing a moving average. This will allow you to take samples however frequently you want without worrying about false starts coming from the accelerometer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Answer (score 1):

When you implement the `accelerometer:didAccelerate:` method in your `UIAccelerometerDelegate`, just have an `if` statement, checking if the time between the last time you got an update if long enough.

In your class that implements `UIAccelerometerDelegate`, you can have a property that holds something like `lastTimeUpdated` and then update it whenever you change your view

Comment: and in the meantime i'll calculate the moving average of the measurements, to get an better value, right?